# Manga image of two girls with unusual eyes

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

[image: I found it on tumblr and i would be interested to know from what manga it is]

I found it on tumblr and i would be interested to know from what manga it is

Comment: you should have used id-req tag which would ask to use google reverse image first before posting.

Comment: Bottom part of the text in the image reads as 隻眼の二人 (Sekigan no futari). This could be a chapter starting page. You can find similar pictures from that manga by searching with these words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as apart of the phase out of image only id requests. [Meta for further reading](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2736/1587)

Answer (score 13):

It looks like it's from [Tokyo Ghoul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul). They've all got eyes like that:

[image]

It looks like the characters from your screenshot are [Kurona Yasuhisa](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Kurona_Yasuhisa) and [Nashiro Yasuhisa](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Nashiro_Yasuhisa):

[image][image]

More info:

- [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/22319/Tokyo_Ghoul)
- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=16086)
- [Wikia](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul_Wiki)

Answer (score -1):

It's [Tokyo Ghoul(Kushu)](http://myanimelist.net/manga/33327/Tokyo_Ghoul) its a really good manga, and it already has an anime adaption.

> #### Synopsis
>
> Strange murders are happening in Tokyo. Due to liquid evidence at the scene, the police conclude the attacks are the results of "eater" type ghouls. College buddies Kaneki and Hide come up with the idea that ghouls are imitating humans so that's why they haven't ever seen one. Little did they know that their theory may very well become reality. ([source](http://myanimelist.net/manga/33327/Tokyo_Ghoul))

Comment: Hello, we prefer to avoid chat-like answers (you can do a chat-like answer but this is too much chat-like) If you removed OMG and :P, and provided a link from myanimelist, you woulda had this selected as an answer.